# Vim gg=G (reindent whole file) without losing current position

Tags: vim

Recently my main work was editing .xml files. Google told me that for re-indenting a file I need to press `gg=G` in normal. But moving to `gg` is something that I don't want. Is there any way to do the same without losing the current position?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the ` mark:

```
gg=G``
```

Or use <kbd>Ctrl-O</kbd>

```
gg=G<Ctrl-O><Ctrl-O>
```

Or `g;`

```
gg=Gg;
```

Comment: I like the idea of Ctrl-O. Might be a good idea to map this combo.